Does the following transition matrix have some special property in terms of finding the stationary distribution?
From a practical problem, I have the following transition matrix of which I wanted to know the stationary distribution:




k
h
s




k
1/3
1/3
1/3


h
1/3
1/3
1/3


s
1/2
1/2
0



I am relatively new to markov models so I looked online for methods of solving them. Through the first method, simple iteration until convergence, I found the stationary distribution to be [3/8, 3/8, 1/4].
However, I still wanted to see if I can infer this from the matrix itself. And while I get the same results using the method of calculating eigenvectors of the transpose, I fail using more straight-forward equation-based methods. I think this is mostly because treating the matrix as a system of equations gives the uniform distribution [1/3, 1/3, 1/3] as an answer.
This makes me wonder if I am just failing at using or understanding the equation-based methods or if this matrix has some special property that I don't know about, making it that the equation-based methods fail.
EDIT: I only just now realized that when I transpose the matrix, i.e. say k = 1/3k + 1/3h + 1/2s rather than k=1/3k+1/3k+1/3s I get the right results. Why do I have to transpose the matrix in this case before the equation-based methods work?
EDIT: Solved, I was a dummy after all. :(

For a markov matrix each column adds up to $1$. In your case the transpose of your matrix has that property. So, in your case, the transpose matrix is the one which is markov.

Aaaahh! So I was a dummy after all, thank you! And the methods that worked then I guess do not really care if you violate that property, I take it? Thank you!

Actually, your matrix is fine. The vast majority of people, books, etc... have the rows sum to $1$. The $ij$th entry should represent the probability of the chain moving from state $i$ to $j$, and so summing the entries in the $i$th row gives the probability the chain moves from state $i$ to "somewhere", and it has to go "somewhere" with probability $1$. (This includes the possibility of moving from $i$ to $i$ itself.) The columns only sum to $1$ for a special type of Markov chain.

The stationary probability of being in, say, state $k$, is the probability you start in $k$ and stay there (move from $k$ to $k$), plus (or) the probability that you start in $h$ and move from $h$ to $k$, plus (or) the probability that you start in $s$ and move from $s$ to $k$. You grab these coefficients from the $k$th column.
